# Ethernet MAC address on Macbook 12"

Tags: macbook-pro, ethernet, mac-address

I am trying to locate my ethernet MAC address on a Macbook Retina 12" using `ifconfig` but I can only see `en0` which should be my wireless card; it's quite baffling. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have anything plugged in to your Ethernet port? If you go to your Network preferences under System Preferences > Network, is your Ethernet adapter enabled?

Comment: Thank you, it wasn't there; but as I commented to the answer below, I think I know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacBook Retina 12" dont have Ethernet port built-in hence en0 is your wifi. Do you use any kind of adapter for ethernet to work? If so, you can use `System Preferences > Network > (choose interface matched with your ethernet adapter) > Advanced... > Hardware`. From here you can see your MAC Address easily if your ethernet adapter plugged :)

Comment: Thank you for your response; I was using a USB ethernet adapter through my USB-C to USB/etc adapter so I think that is why I couldn't see it there. I think I need to purchase a direct USB-C to ethernet adapter then. Thanks again!

Comment: If your USB ethernet adapter isn't Apple branded then you should try manual install driver for it. As far as I know, you probably can get it to work even with cheap ones from China, they all share some common ethernet chips inside though :) Time to googling a bit...